# average number of rolls of a fair die to obtain 5?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

What is the **average number of rolls** of a fair die in order to obtain 5?

So I let my random variable equal:

$$X = \text{number of rolls until a 5 is rolled}$$

Which is a Geometric random variable having the PMF:

$$P_X(x) = p(1-p)^{x-1}~~~x=1,2,\cdots$$

and the CDF:

$$F_X(x) = 1 - (1-p)^{k}$$

and mean:

$$E[X] = \frac{1}{p}$$

Since its a fair die:

$$p=\frac{1}{6}$$

Comment: Average number of rolls=Mean

Comment: $$E[X] = 1 / (1/6) = 6$$

Comment: Yes thats right

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the expectation of a geometrically distributed stochast is $\frac{1}{p}=6$ in this case.

The **average number of rolls** is just a synonym for $E[X]$, where $X$ is the number of rolls.